# shell script-to get the value between tags in xml

Tags: shell, text-processing, xml

My xml file is in the below format. I want to get the value between `<fullName>..</fullName>` tags say ABC and DEF. I am writing this in a while loop to reach each line as I need the value of `fullName` of each xml tag to be taken in another variable. `grep` will display all values together.

Thanks

```
<fields>
    <fullName>ABC</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>TY</type>
</fields>

<fields>
    <fullName>DEF</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>XY</type>
</fields>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use an xml parser, e.g. [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/):

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//fields' -v 'fullName' -n file
```

Note that your `xml` file should be valid, which it is not for your example as your missing a root tag. The following will work with above command:

```
<root>
<fields>
    <fullName>ABC</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>TY</type>
</fields>

<fields>
    <fullName>DEF</fullName>
    <trackFeedHistory>false</trackFeedHistory>
    <type>XY</type>
</fields>
</root>
```

Output:

```
ABC
DEF
```

---

Thanks to @roaimas comment, I created a `for` loop with the results from `xmlstarlet` without knowing the number of fields:

```
numFields=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//fields' -o "." file | wc -c)
for i in $(seq 1 $numFields); do
    var=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//fields[$i]" -v "fullName" file)
    printf '%s\n' "$var" # or do something else
done
```

Comment: @user343860 to pick out each item separately you can qualify the `//fields` search with `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. For example `xmlstarlet sel -t -m '//fields[2]' -v 'fullName' -n file` will pick out the second match, `DEF`.